# Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' while table is empty

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using bluehost's mysql phpmyadmin for my app's database. While testing, suddenly I can't insert and it's showing an error `"DUPLICATE ENTRY '1' FOR KEY 'PRIMARY' "` while the table is still empty. what is wrong?? what is the cause of this issue?

I already tried dropping the whole database and recreating it thru the following:

1. importing recently exported copy of database
2. creating the table one by one thru code (not thru phpmyadmin's "create table")
3. I changed InnoDB to MyISAM (some table worked but some had no change)

Comment: Without the code it's difficult to say, but seems a transaction that you're trying to insert two times the same values

Comment: is your PRIMARY an auto-increment field?

Comment: Yes my primary keys are auto-increment and it was working perfectly fine a moment ago, then suddenly it's showing this error.

Comment: and you simply emptied your table? try running this: ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Comment: Actually, I already dropped the whole database and recreated the tables one by one.